# Eclipse + Phonegap + Sencha touch ==> call to webserver running locally

Tags: android, ajax, eclipse, cordova, sencha-touch

I have installed xampp and mysql on my windows pc. I use sencha touch 1.x.
I have a website running locally. It is under "htdocs/website". It runs perfectly ;-)

I have developped a mobile app (it is under "htdocs/mobile"). I tested the app first with google chrome. In the app there are some ajax calls to the local webserver (e.g. login of user). This works perfectly. I can send a request and I receive a response.

I use the "Ext.util.JSONP.request" to call webservices.

Now I installed eclipse, phonegap and ADT, created a new android project in eclipse.
I start my local webserver and run my app in eclipse as an android application.

I get no errors. Android simulator is started and the app opens. But when I make a call to my webserver nothing happens.

What is wrong?

thanks

---

This is the code of my request to the server:

```
console.log("In checkLogin of logincontroller");

    Ext.util.JSONP.request({
        url: 'http://mywebsite:80/mobile/login.php',
        params: options.data,
        callbackKey: "callback",
        scope: this, 
        callback: function(response) {
            console.log("success");
            if (response.success == "true")
            {
                //save login locally on phone
                this.index(options);
            }
            else {
                Ext.Msg.alert(response.errors.reason, '');
                console.log("failure");
            }
        }
    });
```

When clicking the login button on the phone, I see the message "In checklogin of logincontroller".

Comment: If you are using localhost as the address of your web server you will need to change it. The emulator thinks localhost is itself, not the computer it runs on.

Comment: I did use localhost. But I changed it, so now I use "mywebsite" instead of "localhost". So I have a Ext.util.JSONP.request to "http://mywebsite/mobile/login.php". But still nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the IP-adress 10.0.2.2 for accessing your local web server. The thing is that 127.0.0.1 (or localhost) represents your simulated device, whereas 10.0.2.2 represents the host loopback interface (and will always work even if you switch development machine).

Read more about special network addresses at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses)